# Can I configure software updates to only use OEM kernels?

Tags: kernel, updates, oem

I have a Lenovo laptop that only seems to work properly on the OEM kernels. It's happened a few times now that the ubuntu software updater switches me back to the generic kernel when updating. Sometimes I don't even realize it until I've run into a couple kernel panics.

Is there a way to indicate to the OS that I don't want to use the generic kernels?

Comment: Folks are supposed to be migrating from OEM to generic kernel as their hardware support is merged into the generic kernel. OEM kernels are supposed to be temporary -- a single release, perhaps two. If hardware support is broken in the normal kernel, please file a bug report.

Comment: A work-around would be to use `chattr +i` at your desired kernel or to mount in read-only the `/boot`-partition, should you have one.

Comment: Would be great to know which Lenovo hardware you are using. I've been running Thinkpads since 2005 with "standard" linux kernels without problems ..

Comment: Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 8. I like the machine, but it experiences (roughly) hourly freezes on the generic kernel. I'll look into filing a proper bug report as recommended.